# Attaching and storing images and hardcopy files (more than 100) to .NET application in quicker way and lesser size

Tags: sql-server, file-conversion, image-size, scanning, image-scanner

I have a very generic problem. I am developing an application in .NET, like a document management system. I have a lot of documents against one id (usually more than 100, think of it like a property/land docs or documents for a trial in a court). Now I want to make it computerized and enter those hardcopy docs in a database from my .NET app. So, what would be the best way to add them in computer? I have tried scanning but it goes very laborious for 100+ docs per ID. Is there any efficient way for scanning that much docs per ID?

My second problem is that when I tried to save image file of scanned docs in binary format in sql the size of my database jumped up from 6GB for 2100 images. Is there any way to reduce the size of binary format for images? or any other way to save them in sql?

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have always preferred saving files to disk on a network share and then storing the path\filename in a database table. It seems less problematic from a setup\deployment\maintenance perspective. I'm sure others would disagree though and recommend storing BLOBs (files) in your database.

The jump in size of your database doesn't equal the size of your scanned documents. It auto re-sizes, reserving space on disk to enable to it to cope with future demands. If the database thinks it needs that space, I would let it have that space. You can change auto-sizing off, but that's not recommended if you don't know what you are doing. Best thing to do is ensure it is on hardware that can deal with the increase in size.

Answer (score 0):

To make the scanning more efficient, you can use barcode to achieve automatic document indexing.

For image storing, as sarin suggested, it's recommended that you save the image files on disk and store only the file path info in the database.